# Latex tabularx - add a additional column

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I am struggeling to add a 4th column to my table.. I should insert another HQ 300

can anybody help me?

```
\begin{tabularx}{.6\textwidth}[t]{Xlr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{berechnter Aufstau}} 
    \\  & HQ30 & HQ100 \\
    \midrule
    Ablflusstiefe & links & rechts\\
    Froude Zahl & links & rechts \\
    Aufstauhöhe bei: & & \\
    0\%  FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m \\
    5\%  FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m\\
    10\% FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It would be nice to have a *full* compilable code.

Comment: currently you have three columns `Xlr` so just add a fourth`Xlrr` but why is the second column left aligned and the third column right aligned? I would not use `tabularx` at all for such a data table, use `\begin{tabular}{lrrr}`

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, caption, booktabs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabularx}{.6\textwidth}[t]{Xlrc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{berechnter Aufstau}} \\ 
    & HQ30 & HQ100 & HQ300\\
    \midrule
    Ablflusstiefe & links & rechts\\
    Froude Zahl & links & rechts \\
    Aufstauhöhe bei: & & \\
    0\,\% FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m \\
    5\,\% FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m\\
    10\,\% FM & 3.5 m& 3.4 m\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]